# Find the perpendicular distance between a point and a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that the perpendicular distance from the point B (with position vector $\vec{b}$) to the straight line $\vec{r}$=$\vec{a} + \lambda\vec{l}$ is given by 

$\dfrac{\|(\vec{a-b})\times\vec{l}\|}{\|\vec{l}\|}$

I then need to find the equation of the perpendicular from B to the line in terms of a vector triple product.
Could someone start me off?

Comment: For 1, consider a geometric argument. Draw $\vec{a-b}$ and $\vec{l}$. Remember that $|u \times v| = |u||v|\sin \theta$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė That literally just hit me. I just manipulated  definition of $\|(\vec{b}-\vec{a})\times\vec{l}\|$ to get the required expression.